# Stuck on apache2 default page while deploying Django website

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have gone through a few answers on the web and I am still struggling to get past the apache2 default page. The webapp works fine locally and without apache. I am using an AWS EC2 instance for this on an ubuntu machine.

The whole code is hosted in  `/home/ubuntu/sm`  on the machine, the `venv` is in `/home/ubuntu/sm/venv` and running on the ip addr 3.X.X.212

I've tried adding, editing, removing a few variables, to no avail. I got nothing in the error logs either. The 'gracefully restarting' entries are starting to look narcissistic given how long I've been stuck on this.

`apachectl -S` produces the following response:

```
[Tue Nov 05 05:16:52.198045 2019] [alias:warn] [pid 13664:tid 139764718218176] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sm.conf at line 33 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   ip-172-*-*-29.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sm.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

`"sm.conf"` is the config file used for this, as below:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /robots.txt /home/ubuntu/sm/website/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/sm/website/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/sm/website/static
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/sm/media

    WSGIDaemonProcess website.net processes=2 threads=15 python-home=/home/ubuntu/sm/venv/lib/python3.6 python-path=/home/ubuntu/sm/
    WSGIProcessGroup website.net
    WSGIScriptAlias /sm /home/ubuntu/sm/sm/wsgi.py process-group=website.net

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/sm/>
            AllowOverride all 
            Require all granted 
            Options FollowSymlinks 
    </Directory> 

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/sm/sm>
            <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/sm/website/static/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/sm/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comments, concerns, suggestions, critique of shoddy code, all appreciated.

Comment: You have given same`Alias` for the static and media directory that's why you get error

Comment: Check the docs here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: That's not it. No functionality for media defined. Also, I have switched to that and back. No change

Comment: I found some solutions to a similar problem here: (https://serverfault.com/questions/665231/the-alias-directive-will-probably-never-match-because-it-overlaps-an-earlier-ali) see if this helps